# Why is MIT-Scheme so slow in writing out data?

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

In a larger program I'm writing out a small set (10^7) of numerical digits (0...9). This goes very slow with MIT-Scheme 10.1.10 on a 2.6GHz CPU, taking something like 2 minutes.

Probably I'm doing something wrong, like no buffering, but I'm pretty stuck after reading the reference guide. I reduced everything to the bare minimum:

```
(define (write-stuff port)
  (define (loop cnt)
    (if (> cnt 0)
        (begin (display "0" port)
               (loop (- cnt 1)))))
  (loop 10000000))

(call-with-output-file "tmp.txt" write-stuff)
```

Any hints would be welcome...

[EDIT] To make things clear: the data-entries are unrelated to each other, and are stored in a 2D vector. They can be considered random, so I don't like to group them (it's either one-by-one or all-at-once). You can consider the data to be defined by something like

```
(define (data width height)
  (make-initialized-vector width (lambda (x) 
    (make-initialized-vector height (lambda (x) 
      (list-ref (list #\0 #\1) (random 2)))))))
```

Apparently, the kernel/user-switch takes much time, so it's best to transform this to 1 string and write it out in 1 shot like @ceving suggested. Then it works fast enough for me, even though it's still 20s for 16MB.

```
(define (data->str data)
  (string-append* (vector->list (vector-map vector->string data))))

(define dataset (data 4096 4096))

(call-with-output-file "test.txt" (lambda (p) 
  (display (data->str dataset) p)))
```

Comment: What if you use `write-string` instead of `display`?

Comment: Output to files is buffered by default, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: With `write-string` it finishes in about 1 minute. Still a lot of time for 10^7 bytes...

Comment: What happens if you write 10 bytes x 1000000 loops?

Comment: Then it goes 5x faster, but the different bytes are unrelated, so it's not a logical thing to do (definitely not the nice functional/scheme way to do it) and I'm refraining from taking that approach.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand where the slowness is. It seems like it's just overhead per call to `display` or `write-string`. There's not much you can do other than minimize the calls.

Comment: Yep, that's my guess as well. Large overhead one could say... Other scheme implementations went faster (as far as my experience goes) so I thought I'm doing something wrong in MIT-Scheme specifically. Thanks for your help @Barmar .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that MIT-Scheme is so slow. The problem is, that you call the kernel function `write` excessively. Your program switches for every character from user mode to kernel mode. This takes much time. If you do the same in Bash it takes even longer.

Your Scheme version:

```lisp
(define (write-stuff port)
  (define (loop cnt)
    (if (> cnt 0)
        (begin (display "0" port)
               (loop (- cnt 1)))))
  (loop 10000000))
(call-with-output-file "mit-scheme-tmp.txt" write-stuff)
(exit)
```

The wrapper to run the Scheme version:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
mit-scheme --quiet --load mit-scheme-implementation.scm
```

On my system it takes about 1 minute:

```
$ time ./mit-scheme-implementation 

real    1m3,981s
user    1m2,558s
sys     0m0,740s
```

The same for Bash:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
: > bash-tmp.txt
n=10000000
while ((n > 0)); do
  echo -n 0 >> bash-tmp.txt
  n=$((n - 1))
done
```

takes 2 minutes:

```
$ time ./bash-implementation 

real    2m25,963s
user    1m33,704s
sys     0m50,750s
```

The solution is: do not execute 10 million kernel mode switches.

Execute just one (or at least 4096 times fewer):

```lisp
(define (write-stuff port)
  (display (make-string 10000000 #\0) port))

(call-with-output-file "mit-scheme-2-tmp.txt" write-stuff)
(exit)
```

And the program requires just 11 seconds.

```
$ time ./mit-scheme-implementation-2 

real    0m11,390s
user    0m11,270s
sys     0m0,096s
```

This is the reason why buffering has been invented in the C library:
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Stream-Buffering.html#Stream-Buffering

Comment: The data-entries are unrelated to each other, and are stored in a 2D vector. So I had to change your code a very little bit, but the gist is, obviously, correct and explains the real reason for this problem. I updated the question to reflect this. Thanks @ceving for your kind help.